# Reverse a client-side table in Shiny to click on graph and output

Tags: r, shiny, client-side

https://yihui.shinyapps.io/DT-rows/

In this example, user clicks the row and it bubbles in on the plot. Is there a way to reverse that - user clicks on the plot point, and the table information outputs?

Answer (score 0):

Your input needs a click event like click or hover. like this:

`plotOutput("PlateMap", click = "PlateMap_click", hover = "PlateMap_hover")`

Then you need to handle the event with nearpoints() to know what datapoint was clicked or hovered.

`res <- nearPoints(datafr, input$PlateMap_click}, allRows = TRUE)`

setting allrows to true will add an additional column on res to show what has been selected.

This will provide you with the datapoints then you just need to select them on the table.

To do this you need to call selectrows on a data table proxy. You will need to look at the help for nearpoints and selectrows to get the exact syntax but it would be something like:

```
selectRows(dataTableProxy("RawData"), res$selected_)
```

Comment: Please accept this answer if this is what you needed.